# Magento2 : interaction between a form block and three.js block

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I defined 2 blocks which .pthml are

Block 1 (simplified) :

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="myinput" type="number">
    </input>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($) {

    $('#myinput').change(function() {
        var Value=$('#myinput').val();
        drawSomething(Value, THREE);
    });

});
</script>
```

Block 2 (simplified) :

```
<div id="canvas">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
require(['three'],function(THREE){
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var mesh;
    init(THREE);
    }); 

function init(THREE) {
    ...
}

function drawSomething(thick, THREE) {
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 100, 100, thick);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry);
    scene.add(mesh);
}
</script>
</div>
```

Both are called in the page via layout.xml

But when I change the value of the input, I have an error "THREE is not defined".

Than you for your help,

Comment: Where do you keep three.js lib? Did you properly configure requirejs-config.js in your module to include external library? If so is this library an AMD module?

Answer (score 0):

You must inject three as dependency. I assume that the rest is properly configured.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
require([ 'jquery', 'three', 'jquery/ui'],function($, THREE) {

    $('#myinput').change(function() {
        var Value=$('#myinput').val();
        drawSomething(Value, THREE);
    });

});
</script>
```